# Trying to do a loop with 2 columns and 2 conditions

Tags: python, numpy, loops

I have a dataframe with Microsoft Open, close, volume, pct_chg and close_chg, I am trying to do a condition with 2 columns. If close_chg and pct_chg >0, return yes. Else return 0. This is the code i have below but it keeps returning me an error.

```
np.where(msft.Close_chg > 0 & msft.Pct_chg>0 , 'yes', 
         (np.where( msft.Close_chg <=0 | msft.Pct_chg <= 0, 'no')))
```

> This is the error: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [float64]
>   array and scalar of type [bool]

```
msft['value'] = np.select([msft.Pct_chg > 0 , msft.Close_chg > 0], [msft.Pct_chg, msft.Close_chg], [1])
```

I have also tried the above code, i know it will only return me 1 if the above conditions are satisified. How do I add in the "else return 0" portion into the above code?

Thanks!